# A way to make Eclipse PyDev play a sound on exception?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I was wondering if there is a way to make Eclipse or PyDev play a sound if the console registers an exception and breaks the script?

I assume I could do something along these lines:

```
try:
    function_name()
except Exception as exception_data:
    import winsound
    winsound.Beep(440, 200)
    print exception_data
```

but I would much rather have some sort of shortcut. Is there, perhaps, some sort of plugin that does this, or is this really the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a plug-in that does that out of the box, but does not look like it would be hard to code. You only need to add a listener on the platform log and play the sound when an "error" is logged. Something like this should do the trick.

```
ILogListener listener = new ILogListener() {
  public void logging(IStatus status, String plugin) {
    if (status.getSeverity() == IStatus.ERRROR) {
      // play beep sound
    }
  }
};
Platform.addLogListener(listener);
```

This needs to be done in an eclipse plugin, maybe even in its "start()" method since it does not need any more than that. This [simple tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) can tell you how to create a basic plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like the following :

```
import os
```

at the beginning of your program and then at some parts that you want to have exceptions use the following command.

```
os.system('say "your program has exceptions"')
```